# Convolution in electron-photon interaction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics

Consider the electron interacts with the photon scattered by the nanostructure. After the interaction we can get the probability of eletron absorbing or emitting $n$ photons is $|Jn|^2$ where $Jn$ is the bessel function of the first kind. In order to obtain the electron energy and time distribution, we need to make convolution of $|Jn|^2\delta(E-n\hbar\omega)$ with initial electron energy distribution and time distribution. My question is what these convolutions mean and why we need these convolutions? In my understanding, convolution only represents the instrumental resolution. How can we make convolution between two intrinsic probability distribution?

Comment: It does look like much of a convolution if you have a Dirac delta function. It will just do a replacement. Perhaps you can write down the mathematics more precisely to avoid confusion.